# Ablative considered as an accusative

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, sentence-translation, latin-to-english-translation

In my Latin-Italian dictionary I found this expression:

> arva sanguineo gyro scribo

that is translated as:

> I draw a blood circle on the ground.

But, *gyro* is an ablative. Why is it considered as an accusative?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Latin you provide is actually incomplete (though not incomprehensible). The English translation is not accurate at all.

The quote in question, which appears in the [L&S entry for *scribo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=scribo), meaning I.B., is from [Statius's *Thebaid*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Stat.%20Theb.%2011.514&lang=original). Here is some more context:

> hasta subit velox equitis femur inter equique ilia,
>   letum utrique volens; sed plaga sedentis
>   laxato vitata genu, tamen inrita voti
>   cuspis in obliquis invenit volnera costis.
>   it praeceps sonipes strictae contemptor habenae
>   **arvaque sanguineo scribit rutilantia gyro.** (XI.509-514)

A literal translation of the sad spectacle:

> The swift spear approaches between the horseman's thigh and the horse's flank,
>   wishing the death of both; extending his knee,
>   the rider avoided the blow, but the tip, missing its desired mark,
>   wounds [the horse] on its side ribs.
>   [The horse] goes headlong and loud-hoofed, disregarding the tightened reins,
>   **and imprints the red ground with its bloody course.**

A less literal translation of this last line that captures the meaning better:

> **...and stains the ground red with its bloody course.**

Two notes about the last line that may be helpful:

- *scribo* is used in a less common sense. L&S suggests "engrave" or "imprint." The image is like that of a pen imparting ink.
- [*gyrus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dgyrus) is literally a "circle," but is very frequently used to describe the "careering" of a horse, as in a race.

Concerning the motivating question, the ablative is not functioning as an accusative. *rutilantia arva* is the object of *scribo*, and *sanguineo gyro* is the ablative of means, showing what actually caused the red ground to be imprinted in this way.